# How to fix 'An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden' in AWS Glue ETL Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, etl, aws-glue

I'm setting up a simple AWS Glue ETL job in my AWS Dashboard which is mapping data from parquet files which are located in an AWS S3 bucket to a Redshift database. If I set my Redshift JDBC connection as a requirement to my ETL job, it'll be immediately failed with this message: "An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden" and if I remove it from job's requirements, it'll face connection timeout after a while. When I test my connection using the same IAM Role, it connects without any problems. Is there something that I'm missing here?

I have already tried even adding an ALL Ports inbound rule to the related security groups of the VPC.
I have already tried checking S3 region with Redshift region to be the same. (Although S3 buckets are belonged to global)
I even have other ETL jobs converting data from CSV to parquet on the same region with the same IAM role but they're working perfectly fine.

I'd just simply expect the job to transfer my parquet files data to a new Redshift table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting AWS support, it turned out that there was a problem with my VPC Endpoint Policy. So, I'm answering my own question in case anybody else forget to make sure that VPC endpoint has enough permission to access S3 job buckets including script bucket & temporary one.

Comment: Where do you change that? I have a glue job I created manually, there's no such setting.

Comment: @hey_you You would change that in the IAM role that you chose for your glue job. Go to the AWS console > IAM > Roles, choose the role you need, click "Attach policies" and attach the AmazonS3FullAccess policy (or whatever policy is appropriate)

Comment: Just in case, for me updating the policy only didn't work. Deleting and creating the job again was necessary to get the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like S3 bucket is in different region than where glue job is deployed

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for your answer. However, as I mentioned on the description, they're both at the same region, us-east-2

Comment: oops, i saw ur reply later. Yes, VPC endpoint could be issue.